# Is there a way to add customise fields for each questions when create/render a survey in SurveyJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, surveyjs

I would like to add a tag field for each question in a survey. Currently for creating a survey, the component template code is:
`<survey-creator [model]="model"></survey-creator>`
and for rendering a survey:
`<survey [model]="surveyModel"></survey>`
They have fixed fields only.
Is there a way for me to add extra structures between each questions?

For example, below a question, I could insert a line, which allows my users to add tags and save them when creating the survey:
[example for creating survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFilG.png)
Or when reviewing the survey, I could insert that line:
[example for rendering survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz0Gs.png)

Comment: You should look into directives